# Upgraded nginx, now munin stats don't work

Tags: nginx, debian, munin

I was running Debian 8 and the default repo's version of nginx (~1.6). I changed the repo to the nginx one and downloaded the latest version (1.10.0) and now my munin stats don't work, except for the RAM usage. Specifically;

Requests
Requests/connection handled
Nginx status

...all don't work and produce blank graphs. Nginx works as expected and nothing else appears to have changed. I'm not sure what logs to check - munin-graph.log, munin-html.log, munin-update.log and munin-node.log contain no errors or warnings.

Any advice of how to troubleshoot this is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

nginx_* plugins need access to URL `http://localhost/nginx_status`. Check it by `wget  http://localhost/nginx_status` or `munin-run -d nginx_status` (In the second case there is plugin name, not location from nginx config}.

Also check nginx config. It must contain something like

```
location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log   off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}
```

in the server section